# How prevent date range picker to select same dates

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, material-design

I'm using Material Date Range picker and I want to prevent selecting same dates in range for e.g  when start date is  11-09-2022 end date shouldn't be same 11-09-2022 when user tries to select start date for the second time I want to reset selection. is it possible to achieve such behaviour ? I read documentation but nothing was helpful for me.

```
private fun showDateRangePicker() {
        val calendarConstraints = CalendarConstraints.Builder()
        calendarConstraints.setValidator(DateValidatorPointBackward.now())

val dateRangePicker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
            .setTitleText(getString(R.string.date_picker_title))
            .setTheme(R.style.MaterialCalendarTheme_RangeFill)
            .setCalendarConstraints(calendarConstraints.build())
            .setSelection(setSelection)
            .build()

        dateRangePicker.show(
            parentFragmentManager,
            "Tag"
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

---

You can try to use the following approach, but be careful, because it is Restricted API ("@RestrictTo({Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP})")

```
     val picker = MaterialDatePicker.Builder
        .customDatePicker<Pair<Long?, Long?>>(
            object : RangeDateSelector() {
                override fun select(selection: Long) {
                    if (selection == getSelection().first) return
                    super.select(selection)
                }
            }).build()
```